# using "beenden" for "einen Kurs"

Tags: word-usage

I want to say my german course will be in 7 July to end. Can I use `beenden` for these purpose?

```
Mein Deutschkurs wird am 7. July beenden.
```

If not, what would be the correct verb for this means?

Comment: If you'd like to keep this structure, you either take "enden" as suggested by christian.s or you say "wird ... beendet sein" (will be finished).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"beenden"** needs a subject and an object..

You would say

> Mein Deutschkurs endet am 7. Juli.
>
> Mein Deutschkurs wird am 7. Juli enden.

if you want to say that there are no further meetings of this course, so it literally ends.

You would say

> Ich beende meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli.
>
> Ich werde meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli beenden.

to either say that you graduate or that you abort it.

And you would say

> Ich breche meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli ab.
>
> Ich werde meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli abbrechen.

to clearify that you will abort it.

On the other hand, to clearify that you will graduate, you would say

> Ich schließe meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli ab.
>
> Ich werde meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli abschließen.

Comment: ... and "Ich werde meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli abschließen to similarly clarify, that you will graduate.

Comment: Except that nobody actually uses the synthetic future tenses, especially when a specific date or time is provided. (They shouldn’t be taught in DAF courses at all.) Therefore, *Ich beende meinen Deutschkurs am 7. Juli* or *Mein Deutschkurs endet am 7. Juli* – or what @zwiebel said in their answer.

Comment: @Crissov you should be careful with nobody/everybody, but you are right - I will provide the "common" forms, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The above answers, especially christian.s's are actually a sort of German you would use in letters or e-mails of a more formal character. They are perfectly correct.

For a more colloquial variety, such as people would actually use in spoken German as opposed to more formal written German, consider

> Mein Deutschkurs geht noch bis zum 7. Juli.

Comment: That's an important supplement, although I'd use *dauert*.

Comment: That sounds rather formal, doesn't it?

Comment: Not at all. It's just not as informal as *geht*.

Comment: Well admittedly that's what I meant: formal as compared to geht. At least in my generation I would assume a 95/5 usage distribution for geht/dauert.

Answer (score -2):

Mein Deutschkurs wird am 7. Juli zu Ende sein.

Comment: It'd be cool if you could elaborate ([edit]) your answer a bit. As it stands now it is a bit lean...